# Baby mango tree stopped growing

Tags: mango

I have a grown a little mango plant from a seed all went well until about 10 days ago. The stem is about 10cm long with 5 leaves. The leaves a red, look healthy and are growing longer by the day but the stem size is not changing.
Any advice appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the plant, it looks really healthy.
Leaves are not green as they're young, in the next stage they will become green and get horizontal position, you will see.
Sometimes,

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the tip of the plant properly, but is that a super tiny baby leaf at the end of the shoot? Or is the end broken(it looks like an abrupt end for a plant)? Can you check that?

Either way the plant looks healthy. In case if the tip is broken just give it some time. It will produce new shoot from there.

Comment: Hi Spectra, thanks for your answer. The top looks like a tiny leave but has not grown either. Big leaves are turning green now. I put the plant in a place where it has good light but out of afternoon sun, maybe direct sunlight was a problem. I also gave it a little plant food. Fingers crossed.